# Self-limit heap size in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I am concerned that a C++ program may consume an unacceptably large amount of memory. Rather than rudely gobbling up all possible RAM and swap before going down in flames, I would prefer to have the program limit itself to some maximum amount of heap memory, and have allocations fail when this is exceeded. Ideally, I want to make the maximum heap size a command-line parameter for my program, similar to the `-Xmx` option for the Java Virtual Machine. Short of manually bean-counting every little allocation, is there any language feature which could enable this?

Comment: Do the algorithms being executed justify the memory expense?

Comment: There's [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Comment: You can replace the global new operator with your own

Comment: There's no such standard C++  feature(bar tracking all memory allocations done yourself), but there are probably system specific features that will allow you to control that, such as [ulimit](http://superuser.com/questions/220059/what-parameters-has-ulimit) So tell us about your platform.

Comment: Overriding global `new` sounds like the kind of hack I would be interested in ;)

Comment: @nos I'm currently on Windows, but would prefer to have the most broadly applicable solution.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14144168/103167 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/192876/103167

Answer (score 2):

## Static stack and heap sizes

To set stack and heap sizes statically (i.e. at build time) for your executable you can do one of the following depending on your toolchain.

For **Visual Studio**, setting stack and heap sizes can be done:

- using `/STACK:NNN` and `/HEAP:MMM` command-line options where `NNN` and `MMM` are stack and heap sizes respectively,
- via GUI (project properties --> configuration properties --> linker --> system...), or
- using pragma directive e.g. `#pragma comment(linker "/STACK:NNN")` and `#pragma comment(linker "/HEAP:MMM")`.

Alternatively, you can modify stack and heap sizes of an existing executable using **EDITBIN** tool.

For **gcc**, setting stack and heap sizes can be done:

- using command line options `-Wl,--stack=NNN` and `-Wl,--heap=MMM`.

## Dynamic heap size

To set heap size dynamically (i.e. at run time) you can:

- overload C++ **operators new** and **delete** (malloc and free in C) or
- use an **allocation hook** on your platform (e.g. _CrtSetAllocHook for MS CRT).

In your implementation of the operator/hook, you can limit the heap size (i.e. fail to allocate memory) as you need (e.g. based on a command-line parameter).